# Change page of Primefaces Datatable with pagination from commandlink

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, pagination, commandlink

I have a Datatable with pagination and I want to change the current page with a commandlink outside the Datatable, how I can get it?

```
<p:commandLink title="changePage" action="#{myBean.changeMethod}"
   update="myDataTable" />
<p:dataTable id="myDataTable" var="myItem" paginator="true" rows="1"
   value="#{myBean.ListOfItem}" binding="#{myBean.DataTable}">
  ...
  ...
</p:dataTable>
```

Greetings!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This will set the page of the table to the first one

```
public void changeMethod() {
final DataTable d = (DataTable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot()
    .findComponent("myDataTable");
int first = 0;
d.setFirst(first);
```

}

Or on client side:

```
widgetVar.getPaginator().setPage(pageindex);
```

**EDIT :** The "first" attribute indicates the index of the first row to be displayed

Comment: Thanks for you answer! It's good to know it, but I really want set any page. The `<p:commandLink ... />` is into other datatable, when I click on commandLink, I can know what page number is, Is there any way to set the page with that number? Greetings.

Comment: Oh Wait!!! All I need is in your answer, I thought that with `setFirst` you change the paginator, I only did `d.setFirst(numberOfPage)`. Thanks!!! PD: Maybe if the method name were something like `setCurrentPage` would be more intuitive.

Answer (score 3):

It's ok, but now in primefaces 5.1 on the client side you have to do like:

```
PF('widgetVar').getPaginator().setPage(pageindex);
```

Answer (score 1):

For me works very nice, but you have to type the entire component name

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("form:panel:datatable");
```